# Should we enable a banner to warn about our policy on AI-generated content?

Tags: discussion, status-review, chatgpt, ai

As you may have heard, Stack Exchange has announced a new feature: [Sites can now request to enable a banner to warn about their policy on AI-generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881/162827).

This feature could be useful for Super User, where we have a clear community consensus that posting ChatGPT-generated or similar AI-generated content is not allowed, as discussed in this meta post: [Should we ban ChatGPT on Super User?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14847/10259)

This should help reduce AI-generated posts (and accusations of posting AI-generated content, as lamented in this recent meta post: [Why do people attempt to discourage long well-written answers by instant AI accusations?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/15119/10259)).

What do you think? Should we request to enable this feature?

Comment: The banner should be enabled when the system goes live as confirmed by JNat at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396626/proposed-changes-to-help-center-articles-to-include-mention-of-ai-generated-cont?noredirect=1#396626

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Yes.

It can't hurt. It costs us nothing. People will either read it & pay attention or not, but if only 1% read it & then don't post the AI answer they were about to, then the banner has been successful, even if just to a small degree.

Even for those well-versed in site etiquette, you'll only see it once, so the annoyance factor is low.

Comment: I concur. The banner should be enabled on SU.

Answer (score -5):

While a banner is a good idea, for most people it is just wasted space on the screen.  It would be more useful if

- The banner is displayed to users with less than 200 rep
- Or the banner is displayed when a user is typing the first answer
- Or the system confirms with the user when they submit their first answer, that this is not AI generated content.

Comment: The banner can easily be dismissed permanently so the wasted screen space should be a non-issue. "*All users will see this banner when posting an answer with the option to dismiss. Once dismissed, logged-in users will not see this banner again.*" - [Sites can now request to enable a banner to warn about their policy on AI-generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881/162827)